# Missing $db username & $db pass in configuration

Tags: database, mysqli, joomla

hello I'm using Joomla cms and $db username & $db pass is missing in the configuration file.

```
public $db = 'hello';
public $dbprefix = 'qt1r6_';
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

Only above things are listed in the configuration file, But how it connects to the database without **$db username & $db pass** ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these 3:

```
public $user = 'Your_DB_User';
public $password = 'Your_DB_User_Pass';
public $host = 'localhost'; // or your DB host name
```